# Relay server for generic TCP traffic?

Tags: networking, ip, tcp

Here's my situation:

- I have a computer (Mac) on a school network that I want to port forward TCP 5222 to for ejabberd, but of course I can't.
- I have a server at home (Mac with FreeBSD VM) that I can port forward to.

Is there a simple way to set up my home server to relay incoming and outgoing TCP traffic over port 5222 to/from my computer at school? I know it's possible to make my computer at school connect to the one at home and send/receive everything through it, and I could write a program to do this, but I want to know if there's an easier way. It seems like there would already be a Unix utility to do this.

Comment: `ssh` does port forwarding. That's by far the most common.

Comment: I knew about `ssh` tunneling for connecting to servers through a tunnel but didn't know it could be used for port forwarding. Good idea.

Comment: SOCKS would be a good approach for generic relaying

Comment: A trip through memory lane. I asked this question in my freshman college year then soon found out that they actually gave us each a separate public IP address anyway in the dorms without a NAT.

Answer (score 1):

My home server already has `sshd` running. I read up on `ssh` tunneling as derobert suggested, and I figured it out with the help of some further Googling:

1. Set up necessary port forwarding, firewall passthrough, etc. to TCP 5222 on the server at home.
2. Enable gateway ports: Edit `/private/etc/sshd_config` on Mac (or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on Linux) so that it has the line `GatewayPorts yes` exactly once and no contradictory `GatewayPorts no` line.
3. Restart `sshd` on the server (`launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd` then `launchctl start com.openssh.sshd` on Mac)
4. On my computer at school, `ssh -R 5222:localhost:5222 user@home_ip_address`

Now, connections to `home_ip_address` on port 5222 are tunneled to my computer at school. Yay!